# property 'filter' does not exist on type 'observable any '

Tags: angular

after subscribing, the result has a bool field "isActivate" and i want to check it

i thought that filter function will be good but i get this error

> property 'filter' does not exist on type 'observable any '

```
  getAccess() {
    this.service.getAccessFromApi(this.id).filter(res => res.isActivate == true).subscribe(res => {

    })
  }

  getAccessFromApi(vendorId) {
    return this.Service.get(`${this.resourceUrl}/CheckVendorAccess/${vendorId}`);
  }
```

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using RxJS version 6 or higher then:

Your `getAccessFromApi` is returning an `Observable`, of which you cannot access the valued directly; you need to either subscribe and/or use pipe directives.

Change the code for your `getAccess` method to the following:

```
this.service.getAccessFromApi(this.id).pipe(
    filter(res => res.isActivate == true)).subscribe(res => {

})
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what version of rxjs this is. OP is likely seeing docs from rxjs < 6